# HTML written in vi not updating in browser

Tags: html, firefox, vi

I've been writing a webpage in vi and suddenly any changes I make are not updating when I go to the webpage in firefox. the page still loads, but not with my edits. very confused..

Comment: Try ctrl+F5 in the browser to force a full refresh.  Sometimes that does it.

Comment: And `ctrl+Shift+del` for deleting cache :)

Comment: And once in a while, even Ctrl-F5 won't do the trick and you have to clear out your cache.

Answer (score 1):

As a summary of the above comments:

This has nothing to do with vi. Options to refresh your browser and clear the cache are:

1. ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>*** to fully refresh your page
2. ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>*** to delete the cache
3. Manually clear the cache in the browser settings